High spot at edge of Kerdi Board and Drywall. How to proceed?
So I seemed to have gotten myself into a situation and wondering how to proceed. On the spectrum of the best right way vs the worst way, I want to do a good enough job that I have pride in my work, but at the same time I will be selling this place next year and just looking to get the job done. I think if I were staying here long term, I'd rip out the board and stud.
With that in mind how should I attempt to tackle this not so flat shower wall? From What I can tell, this handyman who added the stud behind this point used a bowed stud and that is where the high point is.(long story; they sucked and arent ever coming back) I did not catch it when it would have been easy to take out and fix it with a flat one. And now that I've laid the floor tile, and banded the floor and wa edge, its not as simple as just unscrewing the kerdi board now. 1 screw is under thinset now.
Where the wall and pan meet it is flat, but as you travel up you can see that it comes off up to 1/4 inch. I will be using 3x10 tile laid vertically and my tile end will be somewhere to the left of kerdi sitting on drywall with a schluter edge.
1 solution I've gotten would be to use a thicker schluter edge and level the tile with thinset. Seems reasonable but not sure how to keep the whole wall flat
Attached are pics.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/tr4otgMDQeW12exM7

I'm confused. Are you extending the tile beyond the Kerdi?  If so why did you not use Kerdi for the entire tiled area?  If you are not, why is the wall board not finished?  ( You should finish the walls before tiling.)  In either case the seams should be taped and mudded.   (This may not be an issue with the framing, but with the wall sheathing installation. In one pic,  It looks like the Kerdi is on a stud and the drywall is below the edge of the stud.)

Tile will extend over the kerdi a couple inches. And I cut the old drywall out to the next stud. So I needed to patch that 7inch gap with drywall. I would rather not hanve to mud over kerdii because I plan on putting a tile bar in front of the shower with anchors .

There are 2 studs side by side where the kerdi and wall board meet and are new additions that a handy man put in for for me so I can have a place to screw in the kerdi as well as mount a shower door. I'm pretty confident the stud is bowed or simply crooked because the one right next to it is a hair lower and if i stick my arm back behind the kerdi, I can feel a gap between the new stud and drywall of the other side.

Sounds like the Kerdi was added before the studs were verified to be even.   Now as Jack answered, you need to fill to make the transition even.

That is correct. I hired out the pan,framing, and plumbing because I felt it might be less hassle. That turned out to be very wrong. Just watching the handyman work gave me enough insight that it really wasnt that hard.
There were at least 8 sharkbites connecting cpvc and copper, and the sealant used on the brass drain to fiberglass pan was incorrect. I had to pull up and replace the pan, and rehire out the plumbing to real plumbers. It didn't even occur to me to check the studs!

At this point I would just tear out everything and do it right, rather than risk constantly chasing issues because things were done half a--ed.

If the Kerdi is flat until it gets to the drywall, with the exception of the mild dip shown with the level in one of the pics, that is minor in the stall. You can screed that mild dip flat if you choose to, then add the setting thinset after the screed hardens.
The drywall beyond is a different matter, and will be on a different plane after the tile is set. Using the Kerdi as a guide. Various drywall makers produce a dry ready to mix joint compound that is typically called, fast set 20, 40 and 90. Its working times are in reference to the numbering on the bags. Some brands come in a 45 minute version instead of the 40 minute. I failed to mention that when I first wrote about it. But those are the working times in minutes.
No need to get the fast set on the Kerdi, if it does, wipe it off with  damp sponge. Use a flat board to use as a screed to get the fist initial build up done. It will be rough, and I mean rough, but when checked with a straight edge, it will be flat across points.
Use those places to use as a reference to get the next coat more smooth but not build up anymore, just fill in the drag spots created by the screed. I typically finish the last coat with regular drywall mud, since it sands smooth much easier that the fast set.
The way I see it, there will be a break in the wall where the tile meets the drywall. The tile will be flat going into the shower, and the wall will be flat from the tile outward.

Great, thank you!

I would suggest using the 90 minute fast set, it will give you time to get everything cleaned up before it sets. After 1 1/2 hours or more, it will be hard and another coat can go over it. After that coat hardens and it is smooth enough, you can go over it with regular drywall mud. It will stay wet for 2 or 3 days, maybe more before you sand. I would get all this done and primed, if not finish panted before setting tile, that way when you use a sponge to clean up thinset and grout, it wont wear on the wall adversely compared to a bare drywall surface.

I hve a bag of sheetrock 45 so I am using that, first layer is on and looking decent. Will update this evening
